# Why I got over quota error ? google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module, google-app-engine-python

I have a project in google app engine, I have backend-module which I use to run long backend process.
this's the configuration at backend-module.yaml file:

```
module: backend-module
version: one
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
instance_class: B8
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

but when I run long running process I go this error : `This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later.`

EDIT:
I want to resize many images that saved in my cloud storage.

the code run when I send http request to a specified url.

so I used a module (basic scalling) to run this long process....

the billing is enabled in my app, so I thought I could run backends as much as I want. right ?

BTW:
my app doesn't crash, the automatic modules are still working good !

Comment: Generally that means your hitting a per-minute quota limit. What are you doing when the error is thrown?

Comment: One of two things come to mind. A) You have a daily budget set and you are hitting it. 2) You are hitting a burst limit. Is it giving you a line number or indication on what call is throwing the error?

Comment: @RyanB thank you for your response,I tried to increase the daily budget , but that doesn't help !

Comment: @RyanB no, it isn't giving me any indication or line number !

Comment: It takes 24h before the budget takes affect.

Comment: Did increasing the daily quota work?

Answer (score 2):

You also could have used more than 50% of your quota before half day, so app engine anticipated that you'd go over and cut you off right away. Here's the message you can read in your console in the "quota details" page, which explains it:

> If your application exceeds 50% of any particular quota halfway through the day, it may exceed the quota before the day is over.

In addition to enabling billing, you have to increase the budget.

Free quotas are different depending on the modules you're using, which explains why your code works in the default module and not in a backend module (there's less free quota for backend). [Details here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Instances)

Answer (score 0):

It means that your application's daily quota is over. You view your application quota details from App engine admin console.

For More info about appengine quota: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Comment: ok but I enable billing, it's not free app, and my app working good when I send the same request from the default module ?